# How to inverse transform the scikit learn pediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a training data CSV and I successfully predicted the target column for my test CSV. The problem is I need to inverse transform the results back to strings for further analysis.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lbl = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

for x in train.columns:
    if train[x].dtype == 'object':
        lbl.fit(list(train[x].values))
        train[x] = lbl.transform(list(train[x].values))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

y = train['target']
del train['target']

X = train
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1,stratify=y)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, max_depth = 6)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',max_depth=6,max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,verbose=0, warm_start=False)

predictions_test = clf.predict(X_test)

lbl = LabelEncoder()
lbl.fit(test['target'])
predictions_test = lbl.inverse_transform(predictions_test)
```

and i am getting the out put as below if the remove the values from the target column in the csv. how can i write the prediction value in the CSV file

array([nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan])

Comment: There is no `prediction` array. It should be `predictions_test` `predictions_test = lbl.inverse_transform(predictions_test)`

Comment: @IronHandOdin that was a typo. i cahanged lbl.fit(y) to lbl.fit(test['target']) and seems it working. the output is array([nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]) if i remove the target column values from the test excel

Comment: can you provide data sample

Comment: this is my test set and if i remove the target column from the CSV, its returning NAN

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Svhc0uGrreEw_OAVipLYnMi7Skl0VV4D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IronHandOdin I don't know whether I am thinking in a right way. I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you labeling your target in your loop and after the loop your target is basicly [0,1,1,0...]. When you try to encode it again you are encoding zeros and ones.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

train = pd.read_csv("test.csv", nrows=16281)
train = train.drop("Unnamed: 14", axis=1)

y = train['target']
del train['target']

for x in train.columns:
    if train[x].dtype == 'object':
        lbl.fit(list(train[x].values))
        train[x] = lbl.transform(list(train[x].values))

lbl_y = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
lbl_y.fit(y)
y = lbl_y.transform(y)

predictions_testX = train
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1,stratify=y)


clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, max_depth = 6)
#clf = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',max_depth=6,max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,verbose=0, warm_start=False)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)



predictions_test = clf.predict(X_test)
predictions_test = lbl_y.inverse_transform(predictions_test)
```